# Points per right answer using php and mysql

Tags: php, mysql, phpmyadmin

I am trying to figure out how to create a system where the user answers a bunch of questions once a week and gets a point per right answer. The admin will add the correct answers the week after so the users answers must be stored in the database.

Would appriciate help how to accomplice this using php and mysql. Thanks!

Comment: I'm supposing the questions will be multiple choice questions. Is that the case?

Comment: Yes exactly, going to use radio buttons.

Comment: @mattesj I made a pretty complete answer :),  let me know what you think

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll need a few pages:

1) Questions page:

In the **questions.php** page you could have a form under each question that would allow for the user to select checkboxes:

```
<form action="answers_submitted.php" method="POST">
What is 1 + 5 equal to?<br>
  <input type="radio" name="answer0" value="3"> 3 
  <input type="radio" name="answer0" value="6"> 6 
  <input type="radio" name="answer0" value="99"> 99 <br>
  <input type="submit" value="Send Answers">
</form>
```

2) Answers Submitted page:

The **answers_submitted.php** page would have to retrieve these values once the user clicks the **"Send Answers"**. After retrieving the answers, those answers would be compared with the right answers in order to get a score. For example, if there were 4 questions in total:

```
<?php

//array containing the right answers
$array_of_answers = array(6,2,"food", 33, "books");

$score = 0;//this value will contain the score once all the code
           //has been executed.

for ($i = 0; $i<4; $i++)
{
  $string = 'answer'.$i;
  if(isset($_POST[$string]))
  {
    if ($_POST[$string] == $array_of_answers[$i])
    $score++;
  }
}

?>
```

Then that score could be saved to a database server, like MySQL for instance and then displayed to the users the following week. This code could be done on page **answers_submitted.php** as well. Here is a simplified example of how to send the information to the database, but I do recommend reading a complete tutorial on the matter:

```
$sql = "UPDATE users SET score = {$score} WHERE id = {$_SESSION['user_id']}";
$stmt = $conn->query($sql);
```

Since the `$score` value was not a direct user input, and since the `$_SESSION['user_id']` value was generated on the server, prepared statements and binding the parameters were not needed in this case, **THOUGH** in most cases these are needed to prevent sql injection. Some coders even apply those methods in all cases (even when not needed) just to be in the habbit of using them, so keep that in mind when making your own code!

Answer (score 1):

You could design as follows:

Have 3 tables

```
Users (id, username, password, is_admin)
Questions (id, question, points, creation_date)
Answers (id, answer, question_id, is_correct, user_id)
```

Three actions

```
    i) add_question
   ii) answer_question
  iii) select_correct_answer
```

User creation and authentication is not peculiar to this problem that's why I'm not talking about it.

Of the three actions listed above, I'll explain just the third one with the assumption that the other two are self-explanatory:

## select_correct_answer

```
    ***This action would take question_id as argument***
    >> admin selects correct answer for a question (simply sets is_correct = 1)
    >> all answers for that question are extracted from the db
    >> each answer is compared with the answer supplied by admin
    >> for each question that matches, the user that answered is extracted from the db and the point for that question is added to the user's total points.
```

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

MYSQL:

1. You can use `WEEK(created_at)=WEEK(NOW())` to get the week's answers.
2. The `GROUP BY user_id` to group by user.
3. `COUNT(*)` for total correct answers.
4. `JOIN` to the table with the correct answers to just get the right answers.

Answer (score 0):

You should create:

1. questions.php page with HTML  (where users answering
   questions)
2. MySQL database with (username, answer1, answer2...)
       (insert answers in database)
3. admin.php (where admin can correct
       answers)